# ArgumentException & process memory keeps increasing in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, argumentexception

I have wrote and modified the source code of the classic snake game. As the level increases, more apples are being generated (e.g. level 1 will generate 1 apple, level 2 will generate 2 apple, and so on.) As i get to level 5, 5 apple were being generated, along with tremendous increases of my  process memory, from 400MB to 2GB. That is where "ArgumentException" error pop up and the game crashed. Sorry for my bad coding as i am still learning.

The error showing to my draw() method where i called every 500ms for refreshing the board.

Error occurs at draw() method in Board.cs

```
public void draw(Position p, Image pic)
    {
        squares[p.getRowNo(), p.getColNo()].Image = pic;
    }
```

refresh method in form1.cs

```
private void refresh(Object myObject, EventArgs myEventArgs)
    {
        mySnake.move(mode); //Move the snake based on mode

        mainBoard.draw();
        apples.draw();  //<----- draw apples
        mySnake.draw();

        //increment the duration by amount of time that has passed
        duration += speed;
        timerLBL.Text = Convert.ToString(duration / 1000); //Show time passed


        //Check if snake is biting itself. If so, call GameOver.
        if (mySnake.checkEatItself() == true)
        {
            GameOver();
        }
        else if (apples.checkIFSnakeHeadEatApple( mySnake.getHeadPosition()) == true)
        {
            score += apples.eatAppleAtPostion(mySnake.getHeadPosition());

            scoreLBL.Text = Convert.ToString(score);


            if (apples.noMoreApples() == true)
            {
                EatenAllApple();
                clock.Stop();
                level++;
                gotoNextLevel(level);
                MessageBox.Show("Press the start button to go to Level " + level, "Congrats");
            }
            else
            {
                //Length the snake and continue with the Game
                mySnake.extendBody();
            }
        }
    }
```

Overal Board.cs

```
class Board
{
    int maxRow = 10, maxCol = 20;       //Max 10 rows, and 20 columns in the board
    int squareSize = 30;                //Each square is 30px by 30px

    PictureBox[,] squares;

    public Board(Form mainForm)
    {
        squares = new PictureBox[maxRow, maxCol];
        for (int row = 0; row < maxRow; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < maxCol; col++)
            {
                squares[row, col] = new PictureBox();
                squares[row, col].Location = new Point(col * squareSize, row * squareSize);
                squares[row, col].Height = squareSize;
                squares[row, col].Width = squareSize;
                squares[row, col].SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                squares[row, col].BackColor = Color.Black;
                squares[row, col].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;

                mainForm.Controls["boardPanel"].Controls.Add(squares[row, col]);
            }
        }
        mainForm.Controls["controlPanel"].Location = new Point(mainForm.Controls["boardPanel"].Location.X, mainForm.Controls["boardPanel"].Location.Y + mainForm.Controls["boardPanel"].Height + 20);
    }

    //setter
    public void setMaxColNo(int x)
    {
        maxCol = x;
    }

    public void setMaxRowNo(int x)
    {
        maxRow = x;
    }
    //getter
    public int getMaxColNo()
    {
        return maxCol-1; //Last Column No is 19, not 20
    }

    public int getMaxRowNo()
    {
        return maxRow-1; //Last Row No is 9, not 10
    }

    public int getMinColNo()
    {
        return 0;       // 0 is the smallest Col number of the board
    }

    public int getMinRowNo()
    {
        return 0;       // 0 is the smallest Row number of the board
    }

    public void draw()
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < maxRow; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < maxCol; col++)
            {
                squares[row, col].Image = null ;
            }
        }
    }

    public void draw(Position p, Image pic)
    {
        squares[p.getRowNo(), p.getColNo()].Image = pic;
    }
}
```

Rewards.cs ( as requested by @AxelWass )

```
class Rewards
{
    List<Position> appleList;
    Board mainBoard;

    public Rewards(int size, Board mainBoard)
    {
        this.mainBoard = mainBoard;
        appleList = new List<Position>();
        for (int i=0;i< size;i++)
        {
            int rowNo, colNo;

            //Generate an apple at random position but not duplicated
            do
            {
                //Generate a random number between 1 and MaxRowNo
                rowNo = (new Random()).Next(1, mainBoard.getMaxRowNo()+1);

                //Generate a random number between 1 and MaxColNo
                colNo = (new Random()).Next(1, mainBoard.getMaxColNo()+1);

            } while (isDuplicate(rowNo, colNo) == true);

            appleList.Add(new Position(rowNo, colNo));
        }
    }

    private Boolean isDuplicate(int row, int col)
    {
        Boolean result = false;

        for (int i=0;i< appleList.Count;i++)
        {
            if (appleList[i].getRowNo() == row && appleList[i].getColNo() == col)
                result = true;
        }

        return result;
    }

    public void draw()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < appleList.Count; i++)
        {
            mainBoard.draw(appleList[i], Properties.Resources.apple);
        }     
    }

    public Boolean checkIFSnakeHeadEatApple(Position snakeHead)
    {
        Boolean result = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < appleList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (snakeHead.getRowNo() == appleList[i].getRowNo() && snakeHead.getColNo() == appleList[i].getColNo())
                result = true;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public Boolean checkIFSnakeEatApple(Position snakeHead)
    {
        Boolean result = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < appleList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (snakeHead.getRowNo() == appleList[i].getRowNo() && snakeHead.getColNo() == appleList[i].getColNo())
                result = true;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public int eatAppleAtPostion(Position p)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < appleList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (p.getRowNo() == appleList[i].getRowNo() && p.getColNo() == appleList[i].getColNo())
                appleList.RemoveAt(i);
            //snakeEatApple();
        }


        return 50;  //50 points per apple
    }

    public Boolean noMoreApples()
    {
        if (appleList.Count > 0)
            return false;

        else
            return true;

    }

    /*public void snakeEatApple()
    {
        System.Media.SoundPlayer EatenApple = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.Eating_Apple);
        EatenApple.Play();
    }*/


}
```

Comment: I don't think you are showing the relevant section of your code. The problem may be inside apples.draw(). A common design pattern is that is called Repository may help you. You can only instantiate one Image for all the apples and reuse it. Could you show us the code inside the apple class? Thanks

Comment: yeah sure...i will edit my question

Comment: `Properties.Resources.apple` - This deserializes the image on every call, try to avoid that.

Comment: What do you suggest then @Caramiriel?

Answer (score 4):

```
   mainBoard.draw(appleList[i], Properties.Resources.apple);
```

This is the problem statement.  The resource designer in VS was not designed very well and violates Microsoft's own coding guidelines.  What is not obvious at all is that the `apple` property creates a new Bitmap object every single time you use it.  Since it is inside a loop, in a method that itself will be called very often, the code generates a *lot* of bitmap objects.

Bitmap is a disposable class.  Not disposing it is in general pretty troublesome, it is a very small wrapper class that can use a lot of unmanaged memory.  If the garbage collector doesn't run often enough so that the finalizer can run, the memory usage of your program can run up very quickly.

The workaround is to use the property only *once*.  Store it in field of your class (outside of a method):

```
  Bitmap apple = Properties.Resources.apple;
```

And fix the statement:

```
  mainBoard.draw(appleList[i], apple);
```

And if you cross your T's and dot your I's then you dispose it when the form closes:

```
  private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e) {
      apple.Dispose();
  }
```

Which is a good habit to get into, although it is probably unnecessary since your program probably ends when the user closes the window.

Comment: You are right: _"Internally the get property uses the ResourceManager class to create a new instance of the object"_. From [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy(v=vs.90).aspx)